# IOS load image from directory in view controller

Tags: ios, uiimage

I try to load image from directory in my view controller. Table controller works fine and load all my images on each cell.
When i add code sample of image loading from table controller to detailed view controller i have an error.

Error "no visible @interface for xxx declares the selector loadimage:ofType:inDirectory:"

```
NSString * documentsDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
UIImage * imageFromWeb = [self loadImage:self.location.title ofType:@"png" inDirectory:documentsDirectoryPath];
```

Comment: Your view controller does not implement method ' loadimage:ofType:inDirectory:'

Comment: but why it works at table view controller? code samples in controllers are identical

Comment: Search your project for `loadImage`. Somewhere this should be defined. I assume it's in a category. Then check whether this category can also be used in your detail view.